# Magento 2 how to hide swatch on configurable product if it is out of stock?

Tags: configurable-product, swatches, configurable-swatches, visualswatch

I don't use MSI and i want so that swatches that are not available are hidden on the configurable product.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

By default in magento 2. When a particular swatch is out of stock. Its is disabled. If no product exist againt that swatch ,

Check in System > configuration > inventory > Stock options > Display Out of Stock Products > No

and after that run

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```